# Check for some attribute value in multiple instances and print another attribute from same instance in python

Tags: python-3.x

To explain in detail, I have some information about multiple workstations. For example, I have 100 workstations which has different name, installed application, user, and department.

I wanted to check for a particular attribute through multiple instances and print another attribute from same instance. For example,

I am searching for the user "xxxx" and if exists print another attribute like what is the machine name or department the "xxxx" user belongs to.

I tried to do this and was able to do it for one instance, like in a class which object needs to be checked, we can mention it with the class.object condition and do this operation.

But when we have multiple instances and checking for a particular attribute in random is a challenge. I tried to find some hint, but unsuccessful. I am a beginner in Python and if someone could answer, would be helpful.

```
from itertools import count

class Workstation(object):
"""Creates an workstation list-object"""
count = 0

    def __init__(self, machine_name, graphics, cad, user, dept):
        self.machine_name = machine_name
        self.graphics = graphics
        self.cad = cad
        self.user = user
        self.dept = dept
        Workstation.count += 1

    def ws_list(self):
        """showing the machine name with department"""
        print ('Name:', self.machine_name, 'Department:',  self.dept)


    def total(self):
        print ('the total count is %d' %Workstation.count)


    def info(self):
        print("enter the machine name")
        dept = raw_input(" ")
        if dept == self.dept:
            print ("the department is", self.machine_name)
        else:
            print ("the machine is not in the list")   


ws1 = Workstation("xxx", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "cad", 123, "IN")
ws2 = Workstation("yyy", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "cae", 456, "US")
ws3 = Workstation("zzz", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "IT", 789, "GE")

print ws1.machine_name
print ws1.ws_list()
print total
```

Regards,

Jay

Comment: What is the problem with the above code? Can you explain more why you were unsuccessful.

Comment: Thank You Pulkit Goyal, actually if you look at the last three lines in the code, to get any specific attribute i would have to mention the instance like ws1, ws2, etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Workstation` class  should not know that there are multiple instances.  Use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) for this.  Here is an example, using a simple list and a filter:

```
class Workstation(object): 
    """Creates an workstation list-object"""
    def __init__(self, machine_name, graphics, cad, user, dept):
        self.machine_name = machine_name 
        self.graphics = graphics 
        self.cad = cad 
        self.user = user 
        self.dept = dept

# this is your database, containing all workstations
all_ws = [
    Workstation("xxx", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "cad", 123, "IN"),
    Workstation("yyy", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "cae", 456, "US"),
    Workstation("zzz", "nVidia Quadro FX 880M", "IT", 789, "GE") 
]

def filter_by_dept(workstations, dept):
    """Filters workstations by Department"""
    # the filtered list is created using a list comprehension
    return [x for x in workstations if x.dept == dept]

print("enter the department name") 
dept = raw_input(" ")

matching_ws = filter_by_dept(all_ws, dept)

for ws in matching_ws:
    # a more portable syntax for string formating
    print('Name: {} Department: {}'.format(self.machine_name, self.dept))

# the len() fonction returns the number of items in the list
print(len(matching_ws))
```

In this example, the `Workstation` class only has properties (no methods). You could also simply store these properties in a `dict` instead of using a custom class.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. While executing this code i received this error
                       
.....(AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len').....
                    
perhaps i should import the len attribute...? Please help.

Comment: I edited the answer but wasn't able to test it on my device right now

Comment: Read about data structures in python : https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you abstrus, i will check this code and get back to you. Meanwhile if possible kindly check this code and provide any suggestions....

Comment: Dear Abstrus, the above code gives "0" for the len function. it asked for the raw input and when i entered the department name, say "cad", it gives me 0 as the output instead 1.

Comment: Okay, sorry !! my bad... for dept i should put the last value... now i have entered IN in dept raw input and getting that 

>>>NameError: name 'self' is not defined<<<

Comment: Dear Abstrus, thank you for the suggestion. The len function works fine... the function >>>filter_by_dept<<< works fine... i just now checked.. for that i removed the second for loop.... so there is something to be done for second for loop... we would discuss the same .... but anyways the above code gives lot of light on my requirement.. I would definitely come back if i get stuck .... Thank you once again..!!!